# Django, Python, trying to  change field values / attributes in object retrieved from DB objects.all call, not working

Tags: python, django, object, attributes

I'm trying to change a specific field from a field in an object that I retrieved from a django db call.

```
class Dbobject ()
   def __init__(self):
       dbobject = Modelname.objects.all()
   def test (self):
       self.dbobject[0].fieldname = 'some new value'
```

then I am able to access a specific attribute like so:

```
objclass = Dbobject()
fieldvalue = dbobject.dbobject[0].fieldname
```

but I want to be able to use the "test" method of the Dbobject class to try to change the specific value on an object's attribute value, but it isn't changing it. I am stumped by this as this is how I thought I am supposed to change an object's attribute value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem or not, but I think you might be missing a save() method.

```
from models import Person
p = Person.objects.get(pk=100)
p.name = 'Rico'
p.save()      # <== This writes it to the db. Is this what you're missing?
```

Above is the simple case.  Adapted for what you wrote above, it'd be like:

```
dbobject.dbobject[0].fieldname = 'some new value'
dbobject.dbobject[0].save()
```

or, I'd write it more like:

```
rec = dbobject.dbobject[0]
rec.fieldname = 'some new value'
rec.save()
```

Also note that depending on whether and how you are using transactions, you may or may not see a change to the database until you commit.

Comment: I'm not trying to update the DB with this, just to change the value within the object, I wrote another method to take the object and save that to the db, the idea is that I want to just update the object with multiple different field values and then to eventually save all at once (by using the other method I wrote)

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to do is sort of like emulating the equivalent of a get.all call which doesn't seem to exist in Django, I guess I just don't understand why I can't change values of the object that is created from the objects.all (just on my local side, as I know I can't use this to update the actual DB)

Comment: You can change the instance value of an object, no problem.  Something is going wrong with your extra fancy stuff you're doing.  Perhaps you're missing a "self." in your init method?  Maybe you intended for line 3 to be self.dbobject = Modelname.objects.all().  if that's not it, then I'm unsure of what you're doing here.  There definitely is a get.all() call, it's like Person.objects.all().  Can you help me understand what you're asking, if this isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure what you are trying to achieve, but shouldn't it be something like:

```
class Dbobject ():
   def __init__(self):
       self.dbobject = Modelname.objects.all()
   def test (self):
       self.dbobject[0].fieldname = 'some new value'
```

Comment: my mistake, I did have it with self in my method in the class, I just copied it over wrong as I had been trying it from an instance of the class also (outside the class, where the instance was 'dbobject'), either way, it doesn't work which is the issue and I can't figure out why

Comment: did you also put the 'self' in the __init__ method?